# Converting list into a specific format

Tags: python

I want to create one material model in one software with the help of python script. The material model can be created like this:

```
soil1_mat =g_i.soilmat("Identification", "Lean Clay 2", "SoilModel", "Hardening Soil", "VoidRatioDependency", True)
```

We can not input list in this curly bracket.

Now,I have a list containing material properties. The list is given below:

```
list=["Identification", "Lean Clay 2", "SoilModel", "Hardening Soil", "VoidRatioDependency", True]
```

I want to create one material using the properties given in list.

How can i create my material model with the help of list?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
ident, leanclay, soilModel, hardening, voidRatioDependency, boolOk = yourlist
soil1_mat = g_i.soilmat(ident, leanclay, soilModel, hardening, voidRatioDependency, boolOk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking with `*`. In your code this should lead to:

```
list = ["Identification", "Lean Clay 2", "SoilModel", "Hardening Soil", "VoidRatioDependency", True]
soil1_mat = g_i.soilmat(*list)
```

Here is a stand-alone example.

```
def func(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6):
    print(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
    print(a6)

data = ["Identification", "Lean Clay 2", "SoilModel", "Hardening Soil", "VoidRatioDependency", True]
func(*data)
```